# BigInt[] postgre in django model

Tags: django, django-models

How can I define bigInt[] in django model. 
I tried

```
   name = models.CommaSeparatedIntegerField(max_length = 500)
   ss = SomeModel()
   ss.name = '23, 23'
   ss.save()
```

It's gives me Integrity Error. How can I slove the problem. 
Using django 1.2

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
max_length = 255
```

If it works then you should check your database type/version.
For example, MySQL prior to 5.0.3 won't allow a field with more than 255 characters. This restriction applies to **Character fields** which also includes **CommaSeparatedIntegerField**.

Answer (score 0):

You should override default IntegerField in this way:

```
from django.db.models.fields import IntegerField
from django import forms

class BigIntegerField(IntegerField):
    '''
    IntegerField dont validate too large numbers so PostgreSQL database crashes
    See: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16747
    '''
    MAX_INT = 2147483647

    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = {'form_class': forms.IntegerField,
                'min_value':-BigIntegerField.MAX_INT - 1,
                'max_value': BigIntegerField.MAX_INT}
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super(IntegerField, self).formfield(**defaults)
```